# Is Autofac ContainerBuilder.Build an expensive operation?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm starting to use Autofac and I can't seem to find an answer to this question.

Also, when should I call ContainerBuilder.Build() ?

After I call the ContainerBuilder.Build() is it possible to register another type or instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ContainerBuilder.Build() should generally be called during application startup before you actually start invoking business behavior.

If you need to register additional components into an existing container you can.  To do this in Autofac v2.2 (or later), you can create another ContainerBuilder instancer and use the ContainerBuilder.Build(IContainer) overload method.

Comment: The `ContainerBuilder.Build(IContainer)` method is only in Autofac v1 I believe. In Autofac v2 this was removed. Since v2.2 you can change containers again with the new `ContainerBuilder.Upate(IContainer)` method.

Comment: Thanks Wim. Somehow you've managed to answer my question with the update method. This way I can call the Build() once and call the update whenever new registries appear.

Comment: Since now, Build doesn't contain a IContainer parameter and Update is marked as deprecated.  Any solution?

Comment: I am wondering the same. This answer is not valid anymore. If we agree that containers should be immutable, that there should be only one per application and that `Update()` is deprecated.. what's the best way to register things that require an existing container in order to resolve something needed to register the subsequent things? I have created a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045767/register-callback-in-autofac-to-be-used-to-register-extra-things

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell you whether or not the Build method is expensive or not, but if you follow the [Register Resolve Release pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx) it doesn't matter because you should only have **a single container instance** per application.

You need to invoke the Build method **once** to get a container instance, so no matter how expensive (or not) it is, **this is a cost you must pay**. However, when you only use a single instance of the container, you **only pay that cost once**.

Comment: Mark, you haven't answered any of my questions and that's the reason for the -1. I have no problem removing it in case you edit your response.

Comment: Did you read the link? If you take a step back and do that, you will realize that the answers to your questions are largely irrelevant.

Comment: Mark, you shouldn't consider my questions irrelevant, since you don't know what problem I have in my hands. If I asked those questions it's because they are relevant to me. Register-Resolve-Release pattern can be applied to most situations, but not in mine.

Comment: @RodrigoGuerreiro I agree, sometimes you may want to segment the application into different units of work (such as what ASP.NET does), and then it becomes a lot more convenient to have some sort of structured way to start a number of R-R-R cycles during the lifetime of the application. The alternative is to use registration keys, but this tends to tangle very quickly and is easy to get wrong. For Autofac, I've settled on using child lifetime scopes, which in the latest versions have a constructor that lets you register things directly into it. Very handy.

Answer (score 3):

```
ContainerBuilder _AutoFacContainerBuilder;
IContainer _AutoFacContainer;

_AutoFacContainerBuilder.RegisterType<MyClass>().Named<IMyClass>("MyNameOne");
_AutoFacContainer = AutoFacContainerBuilder.Build();


ContainerBuilder _AnotherBuilder;

_AnotherBuilder.RegisterType<MyClassTwo>().Named<IMyClassTwo>("MyNameTwo");
_AnotherBuilder.Update(_AutoFacContainer);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my web apps I use a base HttpApplication class that calls the Build on the Application_Start event.
I then use a mix of [Modules](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules) (placed on each assembly that require registration), a [assembly "scanner"](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning) and [MVC integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration).

For later registration you could use, for instance, the [MEF integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MefIntegration), or, as Jonathan stated, use the Build overload.

Hope it helps :)