# Register callback in Autofac and build container again in the callback

Tags: .net-core, autofac, autofac-module

I have a dotnet core application.
My `Startup.cs` registers types/implementations in Autofac.
One of my registrations needs previous access to a service.

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.RegisterSettingsReaders(); // this makes available a ISettingsReader<string> that I can use to read my appsettings.json
containerBuilder.RegisterMyInfrastructureService(options => 
{
   options.Username = "foo" //this should come from appsettings
});
containerBuilder.Populate(services);
var applicationContainer = containerBuilder.Build();
```

The dilemma is, by the time I have to `.RegisterMyInfrastructureService` I need to have available the `ISettingsReader<string>` that was registered just before (Autofac container hasn't been built yet).

I was reading about registering with callback to execute something after the autofac container has been built. So I could do something like this:

```
builder.RegisterBuildCallback(c =>
{
     var stringReader = c.Resolve<ISettingsReader<string>>();
     var usernameValue = stringReader.GetValue("Username");
     //now I have my username "foo", but I want to continue registering things! Like the following:
     containerBuilder.RegisterMyInfrastructureService(options => 
     {
         options.Username = usernameValue 
     });
     //now what? again build?
});
```

but the problem is that after I want to use the service not to do something like starting a service or similar **but to continue registering things** that required the settings I am now able to provide.

Can I simply call again `builder.Build()` at the end of my callback so that the container is simply rebuilt without any issue? This seems a bit strange because the builder was already built (that's why the callback was executed).

What's the best way to deal with this dilemma with autofac?

**UPDATE 1:** I read that things like builder.Update() are now obsolete because containers should be immutable. Which confirms my suspicion that building a container, adding more registrations and building again is not a good practice.

In other words, I can understand that using a register build callback should not be used to register additional things. But then, the question remain: how to deal with these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This discussion issue](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/811) explains a lot including ways to work around having to update the container. I'll summarize here, but there is a *lot* of information in that issue that doesn't make sense to try and replicate all over.

- Be familiar with [all the ways you can register components and pass parameters](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/index.html). Don't forget about things like resolved parameters, modules that can dynamically put parameters in place, and so on.
- Lambda registrations solve almost every one of these issues we've seen. If you need to register something that provides configuration and then, later, use that configuration as part of a different registration - lambdas will be huge.
- Consider intermediate interfaces like creating an `IUsernameProvider` that is backed by `ISettingsReader<string>`. The `IUsernameProvider` could be the lambda (resolve some settings, read a particular one, etc.) and then the downstream components could take an `IUsernameProvider` directly.

These sorts of questions are hard to answer because there are a *lot* of ways to work around having to build/rebuild/re-rebuild the container if you take advantage of things like lambdas and parameters - there's no "best practice" because it always depends on your app and your needs.

Me, personally, I will usually start with the lambda approach.